# Codeigniter: Display data in array, error: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

Ok so i'm trying to display data within an array.

**My View:**

```
echo form_open(base_url() . 'membersController/searchMember/');
echo form_label('Member ID: ', 'memID', array('for' => 'memID'));
echo form_input(array('type' => 'text', 
                      'name' => 'memID', 
                      'id' => 'memID', 
                      'value' => set_value('memID')));
echo form_submit(array('type' => 'submit', 'value' => 'Search'), 'Search') . "<br />";
echo form_close();
if (empty($data)) {

} else {
//displaying the array
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
public function searchMember() {
    $memID = $this->input->post('memID');
    //Load membersModel
    $this->load->model('membersModel');
    //Access the getMemberData function to search for a member
    $data['memDetails'] = $this->membersModel->getMemberData($memID);
```

//The line below is just to test that the array is being filled

```
    echo $data[0]->memFname;

    if (empty($data)) {
        echo "Hi";
        $message = "Member not found!";
        echo $message;
    } else {
        //Load view
        $this->load->view('memberView', $data);
    }
}
```

**My Model:**

```
function getMemberData($memID) {
    //SQL Statement to get a Member from the database based on member ID
    $data = array();
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('members');
    $this->db->where('memID', $memID);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data['memberdata'] = $row;
        }
    }
    $query->free_result();
    //return the array to the controller
    return $data;
}
```

**I keep getting these errors:**

*A PHP Error was encountered*

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 0

Filename: controllers/membersController.php

Line Number: 24

*A PHP Error was encountered*

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: controllers/membersController.php

Line Number: 24

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do these changes

**Model**:

```
if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
}
$query->free_result();
//return the array to the controller
return $data;
```

**Controller**:

```
$data['data'] = $this->membersModel->getMemberData($memID);
```

Comment: Ah thank you so much!, the only other thing i needed to do was change

    echo $data[0]->memFname;

To:

    echo $data['data'][0]->memFname;

Comment: @BrendonRother Got the output?